# Find consecutive fixes which lie on opposite sides of a path

Tags: r

My problem is the following: I have GPS data of a deer and of a street network. I need to identify sections of the highway which get frequently used for crossing by the deer. To do so, I want to identify/select all pairs of consecutive GPS fixes that occur on opposite sides of the highway. To do so, I tried to turn the GPS points of the deer into a line and then divide this track into segments with start and end points at each fix points. After this I wanted to find those segments which intersect with the street network in order to identify the GPS fix pairs which lie on opposite sides of the highway. I tried to do so by using the burst function of the move package to create the segments. But I fail in the next step of saving those segments as spatial lines. Here's the code and the data to see what I did:

Data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nwuisjc5d58ys8r/AAAlV8vy5a4aPnKw-7aJwTjXa?dl=0

`library(maptools)
 library(rgdal)
 library(move)`

Preparing the data sets:

```
data <- read.csv("deer.csv", sep=";")

street <-readOGR("street_data", "street")

data$DateTime <- as.POSIXct( 
       paste(data$LMT_Date,data$LMT_Time),
       format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",
       tz = "Africa/Algiers") 

mov <- move(x=data$X, y=data$Y, 
       time=as.POSIXct(data$DateTime,format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S",tz = "Africa/Algiers"), 
       proj = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.9524056 +lon_0=7.43958333 +ellps=bessel +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346 
           +units=m +k_0=1 +no_defs", data=data)
```

Create bursts in order to create segments which encompass two consecutive GPS fixes (so basically the start and end point). However, here the defined values for num.pos and num.neg don't work, since you only have a sample data. I didn't know how to adjust that though... My theory about what kind of values num.pos and num.neg need to have seems to be wrong. So any help here would be greatly appreciated as well:

```
num.row<- nrow(data)
num <- (num.row-2)/2
num.pos <- trunc(num)
num.neg <- trunc(abs(num-num.row))
num.neg

fun <- c(rep(1:num.pos, each=2), rep(num.neg,1))
track.segments <- move::burst(x=mov, f=fun)

plot(track.segments, type="l", lwd=2)

data.burst <- data[-nrow(data),]

data.burst$burstID <- track.segments@burstId
```

The plot looks actually quiet nice. You can see that the segments were created between two consecutive fixes, as was intended. [segment plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0CRu.png)

And now saving the above created segments as spatial lines:

```
points_to_line <- function(data, long, lat, id_field = NULL, sort_field = NULL) {
coordinates(data) <- c(long, lat)

if (!is.null(sort_field)) {
if (!is.null(id_field)) {
  data <- data[order(data[[id_field]], data[[sort_field]]), ]
} else {
  data <- data[order(data[[sort_field]]), ]
}
}

if (is.null(id_field)) {
lines <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(data)), "id")))
return(lines)
} else if (!is.null(id_field)) {  
paths <- sp::split(data, data[[id_field]])

sp_lines <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(paths[[1]])), "line1")))

for (p in 2:length(paths)) {
  id <- paste0("line", as.character(p))
  l <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(list(Line(paths[[p]])), id)))
  sp_lines <- spRbind(sp_lines, l)
}

return(sp_lines)
}
}


data.lines <- points_to_line(data = data.burst, 
                      long = "X", 
                      lat = "Y",
                      id_field = "burstID")
```

However, if you plot data.lines you can clearly see, that there are segments missing. This seems to be the case because burstID does always kind of skip the connection between two consecutive fixes after the previous two fixes were assigned with the same burstID. So what can I do to save ALL the segments as spatial lines or even better as a spatial lines data frame? Or is there another way with which I could identify the GPS fixes which lie on opposite sides of the streets?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Since the data are ordered in time in your csv, you can use a "points to line" tool in gis to connect your deer gps points essentially as a path and then use "split line at vertices" tool to divide up into line sections. After this, using select by location with the output of "split line at vertices" and the street shapefile should yield segments that intersect your street.

Comment: The problem is, that i need to do this for 35 animals in total. If I used a GIS tool like QGIS I'd have to repeat this step 35 times. That's why I'm looking for a solution in R.